# Activating a virtual environment in Python 3 on Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, windows-10, python-3.6

To create a virtual environment I used:

`virtualenv -p C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe ve`

However I'm not able to activate it. I tried using:

`C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe\ve\bin\activate`

and

`source ve/bin/activate`

And neither worked. I looked around the site and couldn't get any of the suggestions to work either (most of the questions I saw were on different OS/Python versions so that might be part of the issue).

Is the actual set up for creating a virtual environment correct? If so, how can I activate it?

Comment: as I know `activate` should be normat batch script which you can open in text editor. It should change some system variables. DO you get any error message when you run `activate`

Comment: If "ve" is in the current directory, then run `ve\Scripts\activate.bat`.

Comment: Thanks, I just ran `ve\Scripts\activate.bat ` and it returns 
`(ve) C:\Users\David>`

Does that mean that it's all set up correctly and ready to go?

Answer (score 0):

In Windows:

Run
`ve\Scripts\activate.bat`

In Linux:

`source /path/to/ENV/bin/activate`